# what's the biggest integer data type in cocoa-touch and how big can the number be?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit

I think NSInteger, but maybe there's something that can hold larger values? How big can the number be?

Answer (score 1):

NSDecimalNumber [Apple's docs](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDecimalNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html) up to 38 digits
Well it can contain integers up to that size but does not map to a C data type.

what exactly are you after.

NSNumber also can hold long long int.

Comment: Just a little clarification, NSDecimalNumber uses scientific format (mantissa x n^exponent) with n = 10, maximum size of mantissa 38 digits and maximum size of exponent short unsigned int. The biggest number it can hold is 34 028 236 692 093 846 346 337 460 743 176 821 145 * 10^127

Comment: Yes but that noes not represent all the figures in an integer.
The largest integer it can hold without loosing precision is 10^39-1